# Python 3 list(dictionary.keys()) raises error. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Dictionary:

```
error['extras'] = {'expiration_month': 'Invalid field [expiration_month] - Missing field "expiration_month"'}
```

Code:

```
list(error['extras'].keys())
```

Result:

```
*** Error in argument: "(error['extras'].keys())"
```

If its relevant, I'm running this code in a django process that's paused by pdb.set_trace().

Comment: This looks like a nested dictionary. Is it intended to be?

Comment: Works fine on Python 3. What version of Python/Django are you using?

Comment: Works fine on Python 2.7.6. How is error declared? Are there any other code between the dictionary and call to `list()`?

Comment: @merlin2011 Yes, its supposed to be a nested dictionary. I'm interested specifically in the keys at error['extras'].

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `list` [is a pdb debugger command](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands). The documentation states the following:

> Commands that the debugger doesn’t recognize are assumed to be Python
>   statements and are executed in the context of the program being
>   debugged. Python statements can also be prefixed with an exclamation
>   point (!).

So you could try to prefix `list` like so:

```
!list(error['extras'].keys())
```

Comment: @user220419 I'm glad it worked! That's a tough error to figure out.

Comment: This is a pretty old answer, but still helping people. I could be stock in this error all afternoon, but thanks to @justin-o-barber, I could solve my problem fast.